# Where are CSS file being called?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

I am in the process of speeding up my site so i am getting rid of CSS file and Javascript files which are not needed, i have managed to do this a lot through my local.xml. But for the following files there is no reference to them in the local.xml.

options.css.php?store=default

print.css

So my question is apart form the local.xml file where else do CSS and javascript files get called from?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print.css` is added in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`.

`options.css.php` is included by a third-party extension or theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a custom theme and will therefore get closed as a question. My guess is that this is called from the head.phtml template file in your theme. Running the css files through a php file is not default behaviour.

Comment: what about the print.css?